# Is the phrase ‘think past something to something’ an idiom or just a plain verb ＋ adverb combination?

Tags: phrases

I was caught with the phrase, ‘*I was thinking well past it*,’ appearing in May 25’s New York Times’ article, titled “[How I fell for Lisbon](http://travel.nytimes.com/2012/05/27/travel/how-i-fell-for-lisbon.html?pagewanted=all).”

The text reads:

> I met Lisbon in a snit. I was exhausted and impatient and *thinking well past it*, to the northern Portugal city of Oporto and the wine country nearby, my ultimate destination and real interest.

I understand ‘think well past it’ here means that the author’s thought jumped to Oporto, skipping Lisbon.

As I was unfamiliar with the expression, “think past something.” I looked for it in the headword of ‘think’ in Cambridge, Oxford online dictionary and OALD. None of them registers “think past something.”

I think I was confused with the insertion of ‘well’ between ‘think’ and ‘past,’ which can be interpreted both ways of ‘think well’ and ‘well past’

Is “think past something” an idiom like ‘go past (oneself)’, or a plain verb ＋ adverb combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is an idiom, but it is used routinely enough to be understandable. As you surmised, to *think past something* means to *think beyond something,* to jump to the next thing, instead of spending time on the "something" currently in front of you.

Also, *to think past yourself* means to think of things other than yourself. For example, in this [Utah State Today article](http://usu.edu/ust/index.cfm?article=51131):

> Noted humanitarian, award-winning and best-selling author,
>   documentary photographer and Navy SEAL Eric Greitens told Utah State
>   University graduates Saturday that they will be at their strongest in
>   life’s journeys when they are serving others. While speaking to Utah
>   State University’s graduating class of 2012, Greitens told the
>   students to *think past themselves* and to serve something larger.

As you figured out, in your example, the traveler was ready to dismiss Lisbon because she wanted to be gone from there and travel on to what she thought was the much-more-interesting destination of Oporto. So she wasn't giving Lisbon any thought at all, but was instead already anticipating Oporto. By looking ahead to what was coming next, she was missing out on what was right in front of her.

Answer (score 2):

As you have surmised – and JLG confirmed – the expression alludes to thinking past one stop on an itinerary in anticipation of the next.

I've heard a similar expression used rather often in sports.

When a team will play against what is regarded to be a weaker opponent between now and when they are scheduled to square off against a more highly-touted rival, that first game is sometimes called a "trap game." If the team loses that game, fans and the media will wonder if they were ***looking past*** their first opponent (that is, were they so concerned about their second match, that they failed to adequately prepare for the first?).

> The Cougars clearly should not be *looking past* the Bengals,
>   remembering all too well also last year’s game... [→](http://www.ridenbaugh.com/index.php/2011/09/04/carlson-the-bengals-road-back/)

Here's the same expression used in a [1991 headline](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1914&dat=19910119&id=5wwgAAAAIBAJ&sjid=i2UFAAAAIBAJ&pg=1377,3737686).

I think I've heard *looking past* (or *looking ahead*) more often than *thinking past*, but that might just be idiosyncratic to sports.

Comment: I almost added something about *looking past,* but decided its use is different enough from *thinking past* that it didn't fit my answer. Thank you for yours.

Answer (score 0):

I can't justify this with citations, and it is certainly true that sometimes "think past" means something like leaving one thing and turning attention to another--e.g., like no longer thinking of Lisbon and thinking of Oporto instead. And I like JR's example of "looking past" a supposedly inferior team to the Big Game ahead, and thus turning what could probably have been an easy win into a "trap" game--where one is thinking about the wrong topic, about something "in the future" instead of something in the present, about That rather than This.

Yet I have also seen what appears to me to be another usage, where "thinking past" is the chosen phrase rather than some variation on "thinking about the wrong thing," or thinking about one thing rather than another, depicts too sharp a break between where your mind should be and where it is.

So, in some instances, I hear "thinking past..." as meaning, not that one topic is being substituted for another, but that one makes the effort to, say, think out of the box while being very strongly aware of one's current tendency toward box-like thinking and at the same time mindful that something more, something the box ignores or covers badly, is called for, and I am experientially being urged to get beyond this present way of thinking, in the direction of some more open way of considering possibilities.

One phrase I've found repeatedly in searches is the idea that the good life involves "thinking beyond oneself." I agree with those who think being "selfless" is literally impossible, but it is certainly possible to take one's own being and concerns along in a process of trying to live "past" one's individual desires and prejudices. Every parent knows about this option, and every politician ought to.

Comment: "One phrase I've found repeatedly in searches" sounds like you can in fact justify with citations.  Please do per the [help].